# Am I sinning by doing this?

Tags: halal-haram, sin

So. I think I forgot to turn off the auto-renewal for my playstation plus subscription, and I think it took money from my mother. I didn't do it on purpose (by leaving it on), if anything I don't really play on the playstation any more. If I don't tell her this happened, would I be sinning?

Comment: If it was on accident, no. Though be weary of carelessness. Address the situation to your mother and don’t keep it a secret, then it would fall into haram.

Comment: I know, its just that I feel that she may get mad.

Comment: if you don’t tell her, it could come off as stealing her money. Admit to her it was an accident and you didn’t know.

Answer (score 1):

Assalam o Allaikum.

In Islam, anything that you did not on purpose or unintentionally is not considered a sin. You can just go to your mom tell her the truth and she won't be mad. At least not as much as when she comes to know the truth afterward.